# Sql Server 2012 Bulk Insert speed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

If I have a database on production with more that 50 applications using this database for read and write, does it slow bulk inserting (making use of SqlBulkCopy api in C#) of hundred of thousands of records in the database?

Comment: Do you use `WITH NOLOCK` on you Select statements..? do you have access to an run an Execution Plan on the Database? do you have a DBA on Staff? for speed when retrieval of records, do have Indexes setup properly..? and 15 Applications hitting Sql Server, that's really not that large in the grand scheme of things..

Comment: Do you have existing performance issues? Do you have existing resource pressures on CPU or RAM? This question is not answerable.

Comment: Actually I have updated the count. More than 50 application. Sorry for typo. But on my local machine I tested bulk insert of 100 thousands record and it took < 10 sec. On production it took more than 40 second

Comment: This can be contributed to several things, Network Speed, Network Connection, OS on your machine vs OS on the Prod Server , Memory, also you are the only one using your machine vs 100's of people are not accessing your machine. this it too broad and too many variables can contribute to speed and performance